# Error on Task UpdateBackendAPI on AWS StepFunction

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-step-functions

```
{
  "resourceType": "aws-sdk:amplifybackend",
  "resource": "updateBackendAPI",
  "error": "AmplifyBackend.AmplifyBackendException",
  "cause": "An error occurred while processing your request: Transform GraphQL schema file not found. (Service: AmplifyBackend, Status Code: 404, Request ID: f9e800ba-3a10-4d13-a5e9-71adf9e010dc)"
}
```

I have the error up when i try execute the state updateBackendAPI on Step Function , but i check the bucket of amplify and the file of graphql is there.

Parameters:

```
{
  "resourceType": "aws-sdk:amplifybackend",
  "resource": "updateBackendAPI",
  "region": "sa-east-1",
  "parameters": {
    "ResourceConfig": {
      "AdditionalAuthTypes": [
        {
          "Mode": "API_KEY",
          "Settings": {
            "Description": "API Key for schema: schematest_API",
            "ExpirationTime": 123
          }
        },
        {
          "Mode": "AWS_IAM"
        }
      ],
      "DefaultAuthType": {
        "Mode": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
        "Settings": {
          "CognitoUserPoolId": "sa-east-1_oeVlGNYF8"
        }
      },
      "Service": "AppSync",
      "TransformSchema": "type testeModel @model \n{\n            testeCampo: String!\n\n            }\n\ntype Query {\n\norquestrador(input: String): String @function(name: "orquestrador-staging")  @auth(rules: [{allow: private}])\n\ngetFrontend: AWSJSON @function(name: "getFrontend-dev")  @auth(rules: [{allow: private}])\n\n}\n",
      "ApiName": "dhr2knks3nj2aapigraph"
    },
    "AppId": "dhr2knks3nj2a",
    "ResourceName": "dhr2knks3nj2aresgraph",
    "BackendEnvironmentName": "producao"
  },
  "timeoutInSeconds": null,
  "heartbeatInSeconds": null,
  "taskCredentials": null
}
```

Comment: Please do not fill your post with repeated or nonsense content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your post, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your post being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned.  Take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then [edit] your post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

on end of json:

```
....

 "AppId": "dhr2knks3nj2a",
    "ResourceName": "dhr2knks3nj2aresgraph",
    "BackendEnvironmentName": "producao"
  },
  "timeoutInSeconds": null,
  "heartbeatInSeconds": null,
  "taskCredentials": null
}
```

The field `"ResourceName": String` need to be the same of **"ApiName"**